# how to display site name (Tagline) in title, using php?

Tags: php, title

Im trying to display the website tagline on the pages but it doesnt work, my code is like this:

**CONFIG.PHP FILE:**

```php
 
define('EMAIL','email@email.com'); 

define('INFO_EMAIL', 'email@email.com'); 

define('PHONE', '+xx xxx xxx xx');

define('PHONE2', '+xx xxx xxx xx');

define('ADDRESS', ' xxx xxx xxx '); 

define("SITE", "https://www.exemple.com/");

define('TITLE', 'My Tagline');

define("TMPL_PATH", SITE."assets");
```

**My HTML code:**

`Website Title - ?echo $title;?`

**The results I want:**
Website Title - My Tagline

Comment: <title>Website Title - <?echo $title;?></title>

Comment: Edit your question to update your code instead of adding it in comments. Anyway as already pointed when using constants you need to use the same case as defined without a dollar sign. Also keep in mind that using short tags is highly not advised.

Answer (score 0):

you named it `TITLE` in `define`
so, you should use:

```
<title>Website Title - <?php echo TITLE;?></title>
```

Comment: what is the error??did you include your `CONFIG.PHP ` file

Comment: Yes, <?php include_once 'included/config.php'; ?> on the top of the page

Comment: Thank you for your help, anyway that's good to add some details to explain reason of the mistake. @mohamadzbib

Comment: Right now it works, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

it's work, you have to change the name from **CONFIG** to **config** that's the problem.

you can let the filename uppercase but you need to call it as lowercase

```
<?php
include_once 'included/config.php';
?>

<title><?php echo TITLE;?></title>
```